# Ionic Barcode Scanner not to hide when scan is success

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement a QR Scanner using native's ionic barcode-scanner.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/

I would like to scan a QR and stay in the Scanner view showing a modal on top of the camera overlay.

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.scan()
  }


  scan(){
    this.barcodeScanner.scan(this.options).then(barcodeData => {
      this.scannedData = barcodeData;
      this.modal.create("ScannerResultPage").present();
      console.log('Barcode data', barcodeData);
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log('Error', err);
     });
  }
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, unless you tweak the native code.

Comment: You need to write custom plugin for this custom requirements.

Comment: How can I tweak this code? I am using npm to install this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do this unless you tweak the native code from ionic barcode scanner.

Anyways you could do it with [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) (which obviously is the better choice instead of tweaking an NPM Module)

It works with Web and Mobile (so with Ionic too). I used it in some of my projects and it worked well BUT not with Native iOS because Native iOS Safari doesnt support `GetUserMedia API` (you can check the supported browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=stream)) which is needed for QuaggaJS in order to work properly. On Android, Mobile Browser, Desktop and Desktop Browser it works perfect.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know if it's possible to customize the camera overlay with it?

Comment: Yes you can. You can specify for example a `<div id="cameraWrapper">` where your camera will stream and around it you could create your own layout. You can do whatever you want. You even can overlay Content like Cards, Divs or whatever you want above your camera. And also Quagga JS Supports all Types of QR Codes and BarCodes and can even Scan multiple Codes at one time. You just probably need some time to get into it but with Quagga (except for using it on iOS Mobile) you can do anything